# How would I print all values in a TreeMap?

Tags: java, treemap

I have a project that I'm working on for my Java class (obviously) and I must have missed the lecture on how to interact with TreeMaps. I have no idea what I'm doing with this part and I'm not finding a lot of help from Google.

For the first case in the program, I have to print all values of a TreeMap. The following is the code I was provided and the work I have done with it. Everything in case A is mine, but it isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class prog7 {
 public static void main(String args[])
 throws FileNotFoundException
 {
Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);

/*here, add code to declare and create a tree map*/
TreeMap treeMap = new TreeMap();

/*here, add code to declare a variable and
 let it be the key set of the map
 */
String key;

//temporary variables
String tempWord;
String tempDef;

//the following code reads data from the file glossary.txt
//and saves the data as entries in the map
Scanner infile=new Scanner(new File("glossary.txt"));

while(infile.hasNext())
{
  tempWord=infile.nextLine();
  tempDef=infile.nextLine();

  /*here, add code to add tempWord and tempDef
   as an entry in the map
   */
  treeMap.put(tempWord, tempDef);

}
infile.close();

while(true)
{
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println();

  //show menu and prompt message
  System.out.println("Please select one of the following actions:");
  System.out.println("q - Quit");
  System.out.println("a - List all words and their definitons");
  System.out.println("b - Enter a word to find its definition");
  System.out.println("c - Add a new entry");
  System.out.println("d - Delete an entry");
  System.out.println("Please enter q, a, b, c or d:");

  String selection=kb.nextLine();  //read user's selection
  if (selection.equals("")) continue; //if selection is "", show menu again

  switch (selection.charAt(0))
  { 
    case 'q':
      System.out.println("\nThank you.");
      return;

      /*write code for the cases 'a','b','c' and 'd'
       so that the program runs as in the sample run
       */

    case 'a':
       for (String treeKey : treeMap.keySet())
          System.out.println(treeKey);


    break;
```

Comment: +1 for using the homework tag and posting the code you have so far.

Answer (score 21):

Iterate over the entrySet rather than the keySet. You get a set of `Map.Entry<K, V>` which have convenient `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods.

That said, Java's standard Map implementations have an implementation of toString() that does what you want. Of course, I reckon you'll only get points for reimplementing it, not for cleverly avoiding it...

```
for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
     System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + ". Value: " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Is the entrySet a part of the Set class? I can't add any additional classes to the program.

Comment: No, it's part of the map: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#entrySet%28%29

Comment: ahh. Interesting. I might have to try that if I can't get something else working. I want to try and stick to what the professor is expecting as much as I can. Thanks for the heads up, though. I'll definitely look into it further if I don't use it now.

Comment: Unless you have more constraints than those you described, the entrySet should be fine: you still do most of the work and it's more efficient than a call to `get(key)` for each key. I edited my post to add an example.

Answer (score 9):

You can use entrySet(). Every Map in java have this method.

```
Map<String, String> tree = new TreeMap<String, String>();
tree.put("param1", "value1");
tree.put("param2", "value2");
for (Entry<String, String> entry : tree.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();

    System.out.printf("%s : %s\n", key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (String treeKey : treeMap.keySet())
```

That gives you the keys.

Now in that loop, get each value from the `treeMap` using the key (`treeKey`), and print it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `treeMap.get(treeKey)` inside your loop to get the value for the key. Since this value is a string, you could just do something like:

```
System.out.println("The value for the current key is " + (String)treeMap.get(treeKey));
```

Comment: Ahhh. So I would print all of them in the same way that I would print just one after a search. I see. It's so obvious. Sometimes I wonder why I'm a computer science major when I have moments like this.

Comment: @Lish - Yes, I provide an example println in my latest edit so you could see how to do it. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: ah, yes. that would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8+ there is no need for a loop: lambda expressions enable you to print all keys and/or values in a neat one-liner:

```
map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " " + value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the set of keys and then retrieving each value is less efficient than iterating over the **set of entries** (`getEntries()`). In the former case, `getValue()` will have to perform a new lookup each time, while `getEntries()` can simply return the entire contents of the map.

Static analysers such as FindBugs will give you a warning if you try to retrieve a value inside a iteration over the map's keys.

Comment: Do I need to make the treeMap object of another type in that case? I'm getting the following error if I try and use that command: 

`File: Z:\CS121\Project 7\prog7.java  [line: 79]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 7\prog7.java:79: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getEntries()
location: class java.util.TreeMap`

Comment: Sorry. The method is called `entrySet`. But honestly, you should have been able to find that yourself. The API docs for the Map class are not difficult to find.

Answer (score 0):

not specifically about TreeMaps, but about Maps in general - I like this first answer, using **Guava**: [Convert java Map to custom key=value string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166573/convert-java-map-to-custom-key-value-string)